# how to set up an azure pipeline for C++ dlls using MSVC?

Tags: c++, azure, visual-c++, dll

I see how to setup CI/CD in Azure for my C++ project provided it is UWP, .NET/.NET Core, or even plain C/C++ code that I wish to compile with [GCC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/c-cpp/gcc?view=azure-devops&tabs=vsts)(!), but Microsoft doesn't seem to provide any instructions for setting up a pipeline to build a plain old dll written in C++ with MSVC as the compiler on Azure.

Can anyone please show me how to do this or point me to an article that does?